# Filter Multiple Columns ListView C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to Filter to Filter my ListView with multi columns and multi filters, but i dont get a idea how...

[image]

This is my idea: One Window which shows the current selected 
column header where you can select = or > in a dropdown and filter then with your criteria, i only find solutions for one column but no idea on multi filter...

Data load:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\temp\webTsl.xml");
                var units = from u in xdoc.Descendants("sl")
                            select new
                            {
                                EQNr = (string)u.Element("id"),
                                //EQCore = (string)u.Element(""),
                                ArtNr = (string)u.Element("artNr"),
                                Bez = (string)u.Element("bez"),
                                //KundenBez = (string)u.Element(""),
                                //ProjektNr = (string)u.Element(""),
                                //LiefDat = (DateTime)u.Element(""),
                                //EqStart = (DateTime)u.Element(""),
                                //GewaehrStart = (DateTime)u.Element(""),
                                //GewaehrEnde = (DateTime)u.Element("")
                            };

                foreach (var unit in units)
                {
                    items.Add(new Anlagen(unit.EQNr, unit.ArtNr, unit.Bez));
                }


            ListViewAnlagen.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);
```

Class:

```
 public virtual string EQNr { get; set; }
        //public virtual string EQCore { get; set; }
        public virtual string ArtNr { get; set; }
        public virtual string Bez { get; set; }
        //public virtual string KundenBez { get; set; }
        //public virtual string ProjektNr { get; set; }
        //public virtual DateTime? LiefDat { get; set; }
        //public virtual DateTime? EqStart { get; set; }


        //public virtual DateTime? GewaehrStart { get; set; }
        //public virtual DateTime? GewaehrEnde { get; set; }

        public Anlagen(string eqNr,string artNr, string bez) /*, DateTime liefdat, DateTime inbetnahme,DateTime garantiestart,DateTime garantieende*/
        {
            this.EQNr = eqNr;
            //this.EQCore = eqCore;
            this.ArtNr = artNr;
            this.Bez = bez;
            //this.KundenBez = kundenBez;
            //this.ProjektNr = projektNr;
            //this.LiefDat = liefDat;
            //this.EqStart = eqStart;
            //this.GewaehrStart = gewaehrStart;
            //this.GewaehrEnde = gewaehrEnde;

        }

        public Anlagen()
        {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a filter definition, where your item is passed in and a column-specific filter function determines whether the item satisfies the filter.

Lets say you have a filter interface as follows:

```
public interface IFilterBase<TItem>
{
    PropertyInfo Property { get; } // can be used to display the property name etc.

    bool ApplyFilter(T value);
}
```

and some implementations like

```
public class StringContainsFilter<TItem> : IFilterBase<TItem>
{
    public StringContainsFilter(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        // TODO Requirements to check:
        // typeof(TItem).IsAssignableFrom(prop.DeclaringType)
        // typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)
    }

    // TODO Property getter implementation

    public string ContainedText { get; set; } // TODO INotifyPropertyChanged

    public bool ApplyFilter(TItem value)
    {
        // get the property value via reflection and check against the contains filter condition
        var text = Property.GetValue(value) as string ?? "";
        return text.Contains(ContainedText ?? "");
    }
}
```

Ofcourse, you have to define filter implementations for everything you actually want to support in filtering (property types and operations).

So basically, for every column you would decide on the supported filters by property type and let the user select the filter and enter the criteria.

Remains the question how to apply a series of filters... lets suppose the user entered some filters and you saved each filter in a collection like:

```
ObservableCollection<IFilterBase<TItem>> Filters;
```

Then the full items collection can be turned into a filtered items collection like:

```
source.Where(item => Filters.All(filter => filter.ApplyFilter(item)))
```

In order to have a MVVM ready filtered collection of items, I use the following helper class in one of my projects:

```
public class ObservableLinq<TIn, TOut> : IEnumerable<TOut>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<TIn> _Source;
    private Func<IEnumerable<TIn>, IEnumerable<TOut>> _Transformation;

    public ObservableLinq(ObservableCollection<TIn> source, Func<IEnumerable<TIn>, IEnumerable<TOut>> transformation)
    {
        _Source = source;
        _Transformation = transformation;
        _Source.CollectionChanged += Source_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public ObservableLinq(IEnumerable<TIn> source, Func<IEnumerable<TIn>, IEnumerable<TOut>> transformation)
        : this(source as ObservableCollection<TIn> ?? new ObservableCollection<TIn>(source), transformation)
    {
    }

    private void Source_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseCollectionChanged();
    }

    public IEnumerator<TOut> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Transformation(_Source).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }


    // could be a property as well, but this empathizes, that the source collection is not the primary functionality here
    public ObservableCollection<TIn> GetSourceCollection()
    {
        return _Source;
    }


    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    protected void RaiseCollectionChanged()
    {
        var handler = CollectionChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            // always reset as it would be pretty complicated to track the actual changes across all the linq thingies
            handler(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call when a filter relevant property changed on source collection entries
    /// </summary>
    public void CollectionChangedNeeded()
    {
        RaiseCollectionChanged();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public ObservableLinq<TItem, TItem> FilteredItems { get {...} set {...} }

// init:
FilteredItems = new ObservableLinq<TItem, TItem>(ItemsList, source.Where(item => Filters.All(filter => filter.ApplyFilter(item))));
```

Then, when the items collection changes, a item property changes, the active filters collection changes or a filter property changes, trigger an update of the filtered items (item collection changes are taken care of when the source collection is an `ObservableCollection`)

```
FilteredItems.CollectionChangedNeeded();
```

I feel more flexible with this approach than with the built-in filter functionality of the WPF provided controls. Regex based filters, filters for custom property types, ... all possible without much efford per filter type. Just the initial setup of the filtering infrastructure is not really trivial.

Comment: May i ask you for a example?

Comment: Sir, i tried to understand your solution but i don't get it really, may you have a example?

Comment: Maybe I can write one later, not right now... as you can see from the snippets, a ready-to-go example takes a few lines of code and xaml.